# Flash Builder 4.7 Run game shows blank screen

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-builder

I've read a lot of material online and nothing seems to work. Whenever I hit run game nothing gets displayed in the web browser. Also when I go to the project's properties. I select to run with flash player instead and disable the html wrapper. This so also displays a blank box that appears. If anyone knows a way to get the images appear please let me know thanks

Comment: We need *way* more information. How are the images loaded and added to the stage?

Comment: public function Gun(Container:Sprite)
  {
   Container.addChild(this);
   createDisplayList();
  }
  
  public function createDisplayList():void
  {
   this.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
   this.graphics.drawRect(this.stage.stageWidth/2, this.stage.stageHeight/2, 50,50);
   this.graphics.endFill();
  }

Comment: Please edit the question with code, rather than comments. It's much more obvious, not to mention readable.

Comment: Then I create a file that is an instance of this file and add it to the constructor so a basic box should appear at least just for a visual look